# Er kann es gemacht haben vs. Er hat es machen können

Tags: modal-verb, infinitive, grammar-identification

I can not notice the fine difference in meaning between such constructions, would you help me?

> Er kann es gemacht haben.
>
> Er hat es machen können.

and

> Das darf als Vorteil betrachtet werden.
>
> Das wird als Vorteil betrachten dürfen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Er **kann** es gemacht **haben**.

*He **may have** done it.*

> Er **hat** es machen **können**.

*He **was able** to do it.*

This is actually more complicated in English than in German. Because English use *can*, *may*, *to be able to* for just the same action: *können*. Even the past participle vs. infinitive of *to do* is the same in English and German.

---

> Das darf als Vorteil betracht**et** werden.

Present tense passive voice.

> Das wird **man** als Vorteil betrachten dürfen.

Future tense active voice. Without **man** or a regular subject, it's gibberish.

> Das wird als Vorteil betrachtet werden dürfen.

Future tense passive voice.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83511/discussion-on-answer-by-janka-er-kann-es-gemacht-haben-vs-er-hat-es-machen-konn).